# SAFARI : Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list

Tags: javascript, safari

Got this code, that works perfectly in all browsers but not in Safari (Version 11.1.2).

```js
class Account {
 accountFields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
}
```

Getting the following error in Safari debugger:

> Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's
>   parameter list

So I tried to add `()` everywhere, around the array, before, after, etc. Nothing works.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're using a relatively new feature known as [public field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations). It's currently [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#browser_compatibility) by most modern browsers. However, **the only Safari versions that support this feature are v14.1** (released April 26<sup>th</sup>, 2021) and higher. If you need to support older versions of Safari / a wider variety of older browsers you'll need to follow one of the suggestions below.

---

Instead of using public field declarations, you can use a [constructor() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Constructor) to define the properties for your class instances. Using a constructor does have [good browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility) (for IE support you can use a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description)):

```
class Account {
  constructor() {
    this.accountFields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
  }
}
```

---

As pointed out in the comments by [@Baz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062794/baz), you can also use Babel as an alternative solution. Using babel means that you won't have to change your code, which can make things easier on you if you're using public field declarations a lot throughout your project. Babel will transpile/compile your modern JS code into older (ES5 and below) JS code which can be understood by many browsers. You can use [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) babel plugin like so.

First, install the babel plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

Then add the plugin to your configuration file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

For other installation options (babel CLI, etc), see the [usage section](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties#usage) of the plugin's docs.

Comment: You can also use babel to compile without changing your code: '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties': https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: I have the `Version 14.0.1`  and I still get the same error. It's not in beta now.

Comment: @Savandy thanks, apparently there's a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194095) in newer versions of Safari, and so there is only partial support at the moment

Comment: It seems Safari also does not handle symbol `#` private class features very well.  I tested on Safari 10 declared in constructor as `this.#variable = 23` and it struggled where as Firefox handled it like a true champion. Private class feature should be compatible since Safari 9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields.  I used `strict`.

Comment: @Hmerman6006 yeah, private class fields require Safari v14.1 also.  The compatibility table shows that v9 is required to use the `constructor()` method (which came when the `class` syntax). However, the compatibility table shows v14.1 for _Private class fields_, so using v10 won't work for these either. The old way of creating "private" variables was to use an underscore `_`: `this._variable = 23`, although this doesn't actually make your `variable` private, but rather is a naming convention used to indicate to others that the variable is private and shouldn't be used outside of the class

Comment: @NickParsons my bad, you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue, in my case it was working with Safari on my Mac, but not on my iPad.

I was using [deno](https://deno.land/) and [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) to build my bundle, I just changed added the `--target=safari11` option to *esbuild* command.

I changed something like this

```
deno bundle entry.js | esbuild --minify > bundle.js
```

to this

```
deno bundle entry.js | esbuild --minify --target=safari11 > bundle.js
```