# Why do extended classes uses prototypes for methods but not for fields?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, class-fields, public-fields

Looking at this simple code :

```
class Animal {
    someField = 42;
    animalFunc() {
        console.log('animal')
    }
}
class Lion extends Animal {
    lionFunc() {
        console.loge('lion')
    }
}
let lion = new Lion();
console.log(lion)
```

Result in Chrome is :

[image]

As we can see, the instance methods are on the prototype (for each constructor function)

**Question:**

Why are fields, as opposed to methods, not on the prototype?
I mean , `someField` is in `Animal` not in `Lion`.

Comment: Instances share their code, but we want instance data to be unique per instance. Declaring someField static will cause it to be shared.

Comment: Yes, which is why it's not in the prototype

Comment: This has nothing to do with the class being extended or not. Public class field syntax is just syntactic sugar for creating properties in the constructor.

Comment: The way objects work in javascript, **ALL** objects of a class share the same prototype - yes, that's right, there is only **ONE** prototype of `Lion` regardless of how many `lion`s you create. If fields are stored in the prototype then all objects of that class can only have the same value (the fields are all pointers to the same value in memory)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Do you understand why `constructor() { this.someField = 42; }` creates the property on every instance? And why that might be favourable for properties holding data, especially objects?

Comment: Remember: There is only **ONE** prototype shared by all objects. So for example if you create two Lions and named the first `Felix` and the second `Simba` what you will get is that both Lions will be named `Simba` and if you change the first back to `Felix` then both Lions will be named `Felix` because both fields share the same memory address if they are on the prototype (because there is only **ONE** prototype per class). What you are missing is that the prototype is not copied to the instance - all instance point to the same prototype.

Comment: Note that if you **want** fields to be on the prototype you can do it using the old prototype inheritance style. Here's an example of a Lion class: `function Lion () {}; Lion.prototype = {... Animal.prototype}; Lion.prototype.someField = 42`. You can experiment with this structure that you want and see its behaviour. Try doing `a = new Lion(); b = new Lion(); a.someField = 100; console.log(b.someFiled)`

Comment: How do you think it will ever be assigned to the instance if it is in the prototype? It will forever be found **only in the prototype**. If you try to assign to it in an instance, for example doing `a.someField = 1` then it is not found in the instance and js will modify the value of `someField` **in the prototype** (not instance) to be `1` instead of 42.

Comment: @RoyiNamir There is no "lifting". A prototype property is created statically, when the class is declared. An instance property is created with each instance, initialised in the constructor, typically with a separate value (e.g. coming from a constructor argument).

Comment: @RoyiNamir I must say I'm a bit surprised by this question coming from a [[tag:javascript]] gold badge holder, and would otherwise be inclined to close as a duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572), but I feel there's a different part of the picture that hasn't yet clicked for you. Is it about the [public field syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60026651/1048572) specifically? About the inheritance? These really don't matter here, it works the same as without them.

Comment: Confusion on this behaviour has previously led a lot of bugs because people did not expect fields to be shared across all objects. Of course the old-style prototype inheritance is flexible - you can do it or you can not do it. IMHO the reason classes behave this way is to avoid the issue. Remember, the point of adding classes was to **not modify** the js object system at all so that class would be 100% compatible with constructor functions. Doing it this way is a compromise between how objects already behave and wanting a better default behavior

Comment: I agree with @RoyiNamir but I would still leave the reference to the question as it's important

Comment: @RoyiNamir What kind of explanation are you looking for? Why it happens, i.e. how it is specified? Why it was specified like that, i.e. why this behaviour is considered useful? Why there's a difference between own and inherited properties at all? I don't think "*because two different syntaxes do different things*" is what you're looking for. Could you make the question a bit more specific please, and add your current understanding of the prototype/class mechanism?

Comment: @Bergi the question is why and i think i got it now . If it was on the proto then if a child would've changed it , then all other childs would've seen that change. Make sense. Totally. It just seemed weird  at first that methods are on the proto while fields are not. But now i understand

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, although that's only [an issue with mutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared) on the prototype, which get mutated by different instances. It would actually work fine for properties with primitive values (such as the example in your question), or for properties that are never written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior as seen in [ECMAScript - 15.7.14 Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) `25.f`:

```
f. Else if element is a ClassFieldDefinition Record, then
  i. If IsStatic of e is false, append element to instanceFields.
  ii. Else, append element to staticElements.
```

and in `29.`:

```
Set F.[[Fields]] to instanceFields.
```

---

So after we see that this is not a bug, let's see why:

**In simple words:**

As we know if we have a function on the prototype and we changed that function value, it would be changed to everyone.

If we put the property on the prototype and some instance change the property value it would change the property value in other instances as well and naturally this behavior should not happen so we put the properties on the instance itself.

For static properties this is the intended behavior as we only have one instance of them, this is why they are on the prototype

**Extra:**

[this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/151#issuecomment-431100737) comment by [Ranando D Washington-King](https://github.com/rdking) from class fields proposal

*The quote that I mention is about the problem of **add an `x` data property to the prototype [...]***:

> **Every instance has a copy of the object.** The expectation may or may not be exactly that. Consider in Java, the ability to define nested classes. In that case, it is definitely the desire that every instance be able to see the exact same class definition. On the other hand, consider assigning an empty array. The likely intention is for each instance to have its own copy of that array for storing instance-specific values.